# Splitting a file in C using execv

Tags: c, linux, macos, split, exec

I am trying to split a file by using "split" through execv in a C program. The code looks like this:

```
char *args[] = {"split", "-a1", "-b40", "dfc.conf", NULL};
execv("/usr/bin/split", args);
```

While theoretically this should work, it is not working. The file is not getting split. I am not getting any error either.

I am running this on OSX 8. 
Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: I could make the split work using system("split -a1 -b40 ./dfc.conf"); Isn't exec supposed to work too?

Comment: Your code works for me, copied and pasted verbatim (changing only the filename).

Comment: Interesting! On OSX?

Comment: Yes. I pasted the two lines into a main() function, compiled it, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the command at the command line on an arbitrary file I happened to have lying around:

```
$ split -a1 -b40 ll19.c
split: too many files
$ ls x*
xa xb xc xd xe xf xg xh xi xj xk xl xm xn xo xp xq xr xs xt xu xv xw xx xy xz
$ ls -l x?
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  40 Oct 21 20:22 xa
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  40 Oct 21 20:22 xb
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  40 Oct 21 20:22 xc
…guess what appears here…
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  40 Oct 21 20:22 xx
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  40 Oct 21 20:22 xy
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  40 Oct 21 20:22 xz
$ ls -l ll19.c
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  staff  4737 Aug 16 23:24 ll19.c
$
```

So, one distinct possibility is you've somehow redirected errors to `/dev/null` or otherwise lost them, and the command is reporting problems, but you're not seeing them.  Try running with `-a3` instead.  As it stands, your file is being split into 40-byte segments, and if the file is bigger than 1040 bytes, that's too big.  If you wanted it in segments of 40 lines, then use `-l40` instead of `-b40`.

One more possibility: you weren't actually looking for files starting with `x` and a suffix length of 1.  You can control the prefix by specifying it as an argument after the name of the file to be split.

Comment: the file i am trying to split is of about 150 bytes size (only 4 files are created when I use split in the command line).